# express.static handling root url request

Tags: node.js, express

express.static is handling the root url request.
e.g. I want to do a redirect in express from https://example.com to https://example.com/dashboard.
Check the cases below, first one works, second does not. I expect the second to work too. Anyone knows why?

Case 1 (works)

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
   res.redirect('/dashboard');
})    

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')))

app.get('/dashboard', (req, res, next) => {
   //do stuff
})
```

Case 2 (does not work for me)

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')))

//request doesn't come here 
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {   
   res.redirect('/dashboard')
})

app.get('/dashboard', (req, res, next) => {
  //do some stuff
})
```

Comment: changing dist to /dist should make it work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would happen if there's a file `dist/index.html`, because that's what `express.static()` would look for when retrieving a directory (in this case `/`).

You can turn that behaviour off like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), { index : false }))
```

Documented here: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static

Comment: nice answer! @robertklep

Comment: do you think it may have any unwanted effects, or no??

Comment: @maxcc00 not unless you actually rely on that behaviour (in which case an alternative would be to remove `dist/index.html`, since it sounds like you don't really use it anyway).