# Root Route Not Redirecting in Express

Tags: node.js, express, url, routes, redirect

My issue stems around strictly the '/' route. I think this is called the root route. When a user connects to my site, I check to see if there's session data on the said user so that he/she doesn't always have to re-log when the browser closes. If there is no session data on the user, then my website will be redirected to the signup router.

Let's pretend my website is www.example.com. If I go to www.example.com/buy and I don't have any session data on the user, the website automatically redirects to www.example.com/signup as expected. The same will happen if I typed in www.example.com/sell and no session data exists. But if I typed in just www.example.com and there is still no session data, the url doesn't get redirected to www.example.com/signup.

Why is there this 'special' treatment to the root route, and how do I make it follow the same behavior as the other routes?

Code snippet from my `server.js` that I think pertains to the issue:

```
app.get('/session', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.session.auth);
})
.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.session.auth) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/public/index.html'));
  } else {
    return res.redirect('/');
  }
})
.get('*', (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.auth) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/public/index.html'));
  } else {
    return res.redirect('/signup');
  }
});
```

full page of server.js

```
const express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  path = require('path'),
  initDatabase = require('./db/dbConfig'),
  port = process.env.PORT || 9000,
  io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port, () => {
    initDatabase();
    console.log('Successfully connected to port ', port);
  })),
  session = require('express-session'),
  MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session),
  sessionStore = new MySQLStore({
    host: require('./actualKeys').host,
    port: 3306,
    user: require('./actualKeys').username,
    password: require('./actualKeys').password,
    database: require('./actualKeys').database,
    checkExpirationInterval: 60000,
    expiration: 43200000,
  }),
  users = {},
  rooms = {};

// express

app.use(express.static('client/build'))
.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
}))
.use(bodyParser.json())
.use(session({
  secret: require('./actualKeys').sessionCode,
  store: sessionStore,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));

require('./server/routers/router')(app);

app.get('/session', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.session.auth);
})
.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.session.auth) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/public/index.html'));
  } else {
    return res.redirect('/');
  }
})
.get('*', (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.auth) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/public/index.html'));
  } else {
    return res.redirect('/signup');
  }
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help others with similar problems. I was able to find my answer from an older post. I had to add the index property with a false value to express.static.

[express.static handling root url request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203837/express-static-handling-root-url-request)